# ssh-add -l Error connecting to agent: Connection refused

Tags: 18.04, ssh, windows-10, openssh, ssh-agent

I'm using Ubuntu 18 on Windows Bash

When i launch Ubuntu I can `ssh-add` without any problem.
Then I connect to a remote server `ssh user@address`
The `ForwardAgent` doesn't work (git pull, for example fails).
Then I disconnect from remote server `CTRL+d`
I try running `ssh-add -l` and I get `Error connecting to agent: Connection refused`

Everything used to work fine on Ubuntu 14 - I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18 and now I'm stuck.

`OpenSSH_7.6p1`

Comment: I reverted to Ubuntu 16 with OpenSSH_7.2 and everything is working as intended

Comment: I'm not satisfied of `ssh-add` at all, fortunately in most cases we can use `~/.ssh/config/ case instead. For example: [How do I setup SSH key based authentication for GitHub by using ~/.ssh/config file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1097038/566421)

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be fixed in October 2018 update (version 1809) [(GitHub issue)](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3183#issuecomment-426886328).

However you may have not installed this update yet, because October update was postponed and will be released on November 13, 2018 [(Microsoft support page)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4464619/windows-10-update-history).

**UPDATE (2018/12/16)**: I've applied October Update and confirmed that this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by update ssh-agent version(http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssh/openssh-client_7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb)。