# How do I setup SSH key based authentication for GitHub by using ~/.ssh/config file?

Tags: command-line, ssh, git, openssh

I am trying to set up my SSH keys for GitHub and created a new SSH key for the same. I have managed to setup the SSH key but I wish to retain these settings and save them in the configuration file `~/.ssh/config` which is not available. Where can I add this key path to retain the configuration?

Comment: **Easy steps to setup ssh key on ubuntu**
http://collegeinit.com/How-to-Set-Up-SSH-Keys-on-Ubuntu-18.04/blog=5d214da24529de07f8203046

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Here is а short manual how to setup SSH key based authentication for GitHub.** Note the CLI steps for GitLab are absolutely identical, just replace every occurrence of `github` with `gitlab` if you need.

**1.** Install the `openssh-client` if it is not already installed, and of course `git`:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y openssh-client git
```

**2.** Create user's ssh directory and a sub directory where your dedicated GitHub ssh key will be stored:

```
mkdir -p -m 700 ~/.ssh/github
```

- The option `-m 700` is equivalent to `chmod 700 ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/github`.

**3.** Generate the SSH key (the output key will have octal permissions `600`):

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C 'your@email.com' -f ~/.ssh/github/id_ed25519 -q -N ''
```

- `-q` - silence ssh-keygen; `-N ''` - empty (without) passphrase, you can assign one if you want. If it is passphrase protected key, you can add `-a 256` (default is 16) to increase the security of the passphrase by decreasing its verification.

**4.** Copy the content of the file `id_ed25519.pub`, use the following command to output it:

```
cat ~/.ssh/github/id_ed25519.pub
```

**5.** Go to your GitHub account and follow these steps:

- From the drop-down menu in upper right corner select *Settings*.
- Then from the menu at the left side  select *SSH and GPG keys*.
- Click on the *New SSH Key* button.
- Type some meaningful for a *Title* and paste the content of `~/.ssh/github/id_ed25519.pub` in the field *Key*.
- Then click on the *Add SSH Key* button.

[image]

**6.** Create the `~/.ssh/config` file, if it doesn't already exist:

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Edit the `config` file and add the following entry for the new SSH key:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github/id_ed25519
```

**7.** Test the setup. Use the following command:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

On the question - *Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?* - answer with ***yes***. If everything went well you should receive a greeting message like this:

```
Hi pa4080! You've successfully authenticated, ...
```

---

**How to use the SSH key.**

**1.** If you have already cloned repository through HTTPS, by using a command as these:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repository-name.git
git clone git://github.com/username/repository-name
```

Go inside the repository's directory and execute the next command to allow work via SSH:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository-name.git
```

**2.** Direct clone a repository via SSH:

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repository-name.git
```

**3.** In addition if you are using [VSC](https://code.visualstudio.com/) it will work without problems with this setup. For already clonned repositories just use the *Open Folder* option and all VSC Git features will work.

---

Thanks to [@k..a..b](https://askubuntu.com/users/669770/k-a-b) the examples in the answers were updated from [using RSA](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1097078/6) key pair to using ED25519 which is more secure. Here are few references about that:

- [SSH Key: Ed25519 vs RSA](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/90077/131156)
- [Is it bad that my ed25519 key is so short compared to a RSA key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/101044/131156)
- [Upgrade Your SSH Key to Ed25519](https://medium.com/risan/upgrade-your-ssh-key-to-ed25519-c6e8d60d3c54)
- [How to secure your SSH server with
  public key Ed25519 Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://cryptsus.com/blog/how-to-secure-your-ssh-server-with-public-key-elliptic-curve-ed25519-crypto.html)

Comment: It's not on the Profile, it's on the Settings.

Comment: Hi, @tomasantunes, you are right. I've updated the answer. Time ago the menu was different :)

Answer (score 1):

this file is not available by default. You have to create it.
Please be aware SSH keys and `~/.ssh/config` are separate files (with different purpose).

your SSH keys are stored in ~/.ssh (use `ls -al ~/.ssh` to see them all)
and your SSH config is stored in the `~/.ssh/config`. If you don't have it feel free to use `touch ~/.ssh/config` to create it.

If you want to use your key with GitHub/Bitbucket/GitLab use the following:

Start the ssh-agent in the background:

```
eval $('ssh-agent -s')
```

Then add the SSH private key to the ssh-agent and store your passphrase (if created) in the keychain:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

In the above case `id_ed25519` is your private SSH key file. If you have a different name for your private key, likely because you used a different cryptographic algorithm (i.e. `RSA` or `ECDSA`) just change it to your real private key file name.

If key pair is generated with RSA algorithm it should appears as follows:

```
ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Else, it will appears as so if keys are generated with ECDSA:

```
ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
```

Comment: There is a strange problem where if the ~/.ssh/config file doesn't exist then the configuration settings don't set. Best to always create it if it doesn't exist.