# rsync to another machine within the same wifi

Tags: networking, ssh, rsync

I routinely backup my books to another computer within the same wifi,

```
rsync -avlu --exclude=".git" ~/Documents/Books beta@192.168.31.90:~/Documents/Books
rsync -avlu --exclude={.git,.DS_Store}" ~/Documents/Books beta@192.168.31.90:~/Documents/Books
```

Everytime, I should remember the ip address of destination machine.

Tried @local and @localhost but failed.

How could I use a name rather than a series of numbers?

Comment: I made Truck.app (an rsync app) to make this easier.  Excuse the shameless plug but perhaps it will help you -> http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose you need to setup `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

The content of the file should look as:

```bsh
Host my-destination-host
    HostName 192.168.31.90
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User beta
    Port 22

Host another-example
    HostName 222.222.22.222
    User another-user
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another-path/id_rsa
    Port 2233
    RemoteForward 6900 127.0.0.1:5900
    RemoteForward 3389 192.168.100.115:3389
    Compression yes
    CompressionLevel 6

# etc.
```

Once the file is saved, you will be able to ssh to `beta@192.168.31.90` by the command:

```bsh
ssh my-destination-host
```

or for the another example - note the Tab completion is applicable for the Host names:

```
ssh another-exampTab ↹
```

Respectively most of the commands that use ssh can use the configuration file. For example `rsync`:

```bsh
rsync -avlu --exclude=".git" ~/Documents/Books my-destination-host:~/Documents/Books
```

*References and more examples, where the `~/.ssh/config` file is used:*

- *[Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/987769/566421)*
- *[Permission denied when trying to run a script that uses 'sshpass'](https://askubuntu.com/q/986179/566421)*
- *[How do I setup SSH key based authentication for GitHub by using ~/.ssh/config file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1097038/566421)*
- *[Ubuntu Documentation - Community Help Wiki: SSH/OpenSSH/Keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)*

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the 'dot local' hostname?

```
rsync -avlu --exclude=".git" ~/Documents/Books beta@my-machine.local:~/Documents/Books
```

On the receiving machine, go to System Preferences -> Sharing.  Next to 'computer name' click 'edit'.  Then copy the address.  Mine, for instance, is 'terminal-36.local'.

Also consider specifying `--rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -o AddressFamily=inet`.  Resolving .local hostnames to IPv6 has always caused me bother (but perhaps you'll be luckier).